# Wordpress - How to exclude a category from being shown

Tags: php, wordpress

```
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <ul class="category-filters">
            <?php
                $args = array(
                    'parent' => 0,
                    'exclude' => '1, 9'
                );
                $cats = get_categories($args);

                foreach($cats as $cat) {
                    $output =
                        '<li>
                            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="' . $cat->cat_name . '">'
                            . $cat->cat_name .
                        '</li>';
                    echo $output;
                }
            ?>
        </ul>

        <h4>Meet our Coaches</h4>

        <?php
            $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));

            if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="callout horizontal word-wrap"
                     data-category="
                        <?php
                            $cats=get_the_category();
                            echo $cats[0]->cat_name;
                        ?>">

                    <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>

                    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
```

I have the above php. It creates a list of checkboxes and then creates a list on callouts looping through all of the categories in wordpress.

I would like to know how I could modify this code so that it never creates and checkboxes or callouts for the category 'coaching'.

In addition to this question it would be great to know if there is a better way to get my desired outcome through something that wordpress has to offer that I have missed.

Comment: `if (category name != coaching) { output category }`

Comment: What would happen if the name of Coaching changes in the future?

Comment: `if (category id != $id of coaching) { output category }`

Comment: Cheers. I can't work out how to not show the callout though.. I've done the list

Comment: Got it Cheers again

Comment: $args = array(
                    'parent' => 0,
                    'exclude' => array(1, 9)
                );  would have done your jobe easy and clean

Comment: Mickey, How does this even work!